# Get correct id from facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get a username from facebook id - I found a way to do it:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/id?fields=link
```

however, i noticed that using the graph api, when writing 'me' in the fileds I get a different id from when I use this site :`http://findmyfacebookid.com/`
And only when using the id from the `http://findmyfacebookid.com/` site, the `https://graph.facebook.com/id?fields=link` works

Anyone knows how to get the id that works every time using the graph api?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since v2.0 you only get an "App Scoped ID", there is no way to get the "real" ID anymore, and there is no way to get the "username" either. See the [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) for more information.

You should not need the username anyway. If you want to identify returning users, you can just use the App Scoped ID. And if you need to match user between different Apps, you can use the [Business Mapping API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business).